# DeleteDatabase is not supported by the provider, Oracle with Entity Framework

Tags: oracle, entity-framework, odac

I'm using Model-First approach and Oracle database.

**Update2: Fixed Now**

On including `seed` data, I'm getting this error **"DeleteDatabase is not supported by the provider"**

**UPDATE1** If I change seed data type from
`public class MySeedData : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<ToolContext>` to
 `public class MySeedData : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<ToolContext>`
this error is replaced by another error:

`Exception Model compatibility cannot be checked because the DbContext instance was not created using Code First patterns. DbContext instances created from an ObjectContext or using an EDMX file cannot be checked for compatibility`

**Seed Data**

```
 public class MySeedData : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<ToolContext>
    {
        protected override void Seed(ToolContext context)
        {
            base.Seed(context);

            var category = new List<CategoryValue>
            {
                new CategoryValue{Id=1, Name = "Associate"},
                new CategoryValue{Id =2, Name = "Professional"},
                new CategoryValue{Id=3, Name = "Master"},
                new CategoryValue{Id = 4, Name = "Product"},
                new CategoryValue{Id = 5, Name = "Portfolio"}
            };

            category.ForEach(cert => context.CategoryValues.Add(cert));
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

**Web.Config**

```
 <connectionStrings>
    <add name="LMSPriorToolContext" 
           connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.LMSPriorToolModel.csdl|res://*/Models.LMSPriorToolModel.ssdl|res://*/Models.LMSPriorToolModel.msl;
provider=Oracle.DataAccess.Client;
provider connection string=&quot;DATA SOURCE=DEV;PASSWORD=1234;PERSIST SECURITY INFO=True;USER ID=abc&quot;" 
providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

**Application_Start()**

```
Database.SetInitializer<ToolContext>(new SeedData());
```

**Main.cs: EXCEPTION RAISED IN THIS FILE** I know when you first try to access database, seed data method or scripts are executed.

```
 using (var dbContext = new ToolContext())
        {
            var items = dbContext.CategoryValues;

            foreach(CategoryValue category in **items**)  // **Getting error here**
            {
                Console.WriteLine(category.Name);
            }
        }
```

**REFERENCES** Seems like I'm missing something here as there is nothing related to Oracle or ODAC

[image: References]

**Stack Trace**

```
 at System.Data.Common.DbProviderServices.DbDeleteDatabase(DbConnection connection, Nullable`1 commandTimeout, StoreItemCollection storeItemCollection)
   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.DeleteDatabase()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.DatabaseOperations.DeleteIfExists(ObjectContext objectContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Database.Delete()
   at System.Data.Entity.DropCreateDatabaseAlways`1.InitializeDatabase(TContext context)
   at System.Data.Entity.Database.<>c__DisplayClass2`1.<SetInitializerInternal>b__0(DbContext c)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.<>c__DisplayClass8.<PerformDatabaseInitialization>b__6()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformInitializationAction(Action action)
```

Please suggest what I'm missing here.

Comment: What version of Oracle.DataAccess.dll do you have on your system?

Comment: 11.2.0.3 but for database I'm using Oracle10g. Also check another error in question

Comment: This link says Seeding is not supported in Model First: http://forums.asp.net/t/1722132.aspx/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Way of seeding data using `DropCreateDatabaseAlways or DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges` is not supported in Model-First approach.

Change seed data class to:

```
public class ToolSeedData : IDatabaseInitializer<ToolContext>
{
    public void InitializeDatabase(ToolContext context)
    {
        var category = new List<CategoryValue>
        {
            new CategoryValue{Id=1, Name = "Associate"},
            new CategoryValue{Id =2, Name = "Professional"},
            new CategoryValue{Id=3, Name = "Master"},
            new CategoryValue{Id = 4, Name = "Product"},
            new CategoryValue{Id = 5, Name = "Portfolio"}
        };

        category.ForEach(cert => context.CategoryValues.Add(cert));

        context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Possible error if you don't use it:

> 1. DeleteDatabase is not supported by the provider
> 2. Exception Model compatibility cannot be checked because the DbContext instance was not created using Code First patterns.
>      DbContext instances created from an ObjectContext or using an EDMX
>      file cannot be checked for compatibility

Microsoft link [Seeding database does not work](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/558163f0-d4be-43a7-aac3-2df339578e28/entity-framework-41-aspnet-mvc3-seeding-database-does-not-work)

Hope this helps someone else.